# Xcode 4 showing SVN warnings for other Projects

Tags: xcode, svn, xcode4

I just upgraded to Xcode 4 and I'm still orienting myself with all of the new features, but I'm running into a weird problem. I opened one of my projects and the issues navigator is showing warnings from other projects in the same SVN repository.

My SVN repository is structured like this:

```
SVNRoot/ProjectA/
SVNRoot/ProjectA/branches/
SVNRoot/ProjectA/tags/
SVNRoot/ProjectA/trunk/
SVNRoot/ProjectA/trunk/ProjectA/
SVNRoot/ProjectA/trunk/ProjectA/ProjectA.xcodeproj

SVNRoot/ProjectB/
SVNRoot/ProjectB/branches/
SVNRoot/ProjectB/tags/
SVNRoot/ProjectB/trunk/
SVNRoot/ProjectB/trunk/ProjectB/
SVNRoot/ProjectB/trunk/ProjectB/ProjectB.xcodeproj
```

When I open ProjectA.xcodeproj in XCode, the issues navigator is giving me warnings in Project B about files "missing from working copy."

Does XCode 4 expect me to have separate respositories for each of my projects? That seems fairly onerous when it comes to administration considering I've got like 30 apps each with their own project and adding more every week.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This other question posted by Scott has some good info in it, but in the end I had to break up my SVN repository into many repositories (one for each project). Not only did it make the errors go away, but it also made Xcode 4 run MUCH faster.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem (though not exactly the same as yours).  There are quite a few answers at this similar post that may help you out.  [Missing file warnings showing up after upgrade to XCode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292291/missing-file-warnings-showing-up-after-upgrade-to-xcode-4)