# Can you disable version control integration in Xcode 4?

Tags: xcode, svn, version-control

I use [Cornerstone](http://www.zennaware.com/cornerstone/) for managing my Subversion repositories, so I don't need Xcode's integration, and I'm noticing Xcode is dumping loads of SVN-related output into my console (it recognises that my project is a local SVN copy)...

In particular, there are loads of `ERROR: Your working copy returned an SVN status of "external" that we don't handle (yet)` messages due to my svn:externals.

This has to be slowing the IDE down - does anyone know of any way to disable the SVN integration in Xcode 4?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Right! This seems to stop it for good - simply rename the following package to something other than IDESubversion.ideplugin (I've renamed mine `IDESubversion-DISABLED.ideplugin`)...

**Xcode 5.1+**
This is finally a built-in Xcode preference - [see @MANIAK_dobrii's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466254/can-you-disable-version-control-integration-in-xcode-4/22427108#22427108) for details.

**Xcode 5/Xcode 4.3+:**
`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDESubversion.ideplugin`

**Xcode 4.0 - 4.2:**
`/Developer/Library/Xcode/PrivatePlugIns/IDESubversion.ideplugin`

Note that in Xcode 4.0 & 4.1 (and possibly 4.2) renaming the extension seemed to work fine. From Xcode 4.3 however, you might need to leave the extension intact, and rename the name portion of the bundle instead (to avoid the error on launch that people have described in the comments below).

Tip o' the hat to: [Remove git from project in Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526366/remove-git-from-project-in-xcode-4)

Comment: I just spent a day trying to stop the damn plugin from ruining my SVN repo. Big thanks for this solution!

Comment: Yep, finally a solution for permanently disabling version control on xcode 4. Thanks!

Comment: This worked fine since now. Yesterday I updated to the new 4.2 version and the plugin appeared again. If I remove it Xcode fails stating because of a missing component.

Comment: Renaming the plugin still works for me with the 4D199 GM build of Xcode 4.2 that was release to the dev portal last week...

Comment: Update for Xcode 4.3: this still works, plugins are now located at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns

Comment: This does not still work for XCode 4.3 or 4.2. You get a missing components dialog, and XCode refuses to run.

Comment: Pretty strange - works on all my Xcode installations, on multiple machines. What are you renaming the file to?

Comment: Worked for me on Lion with Xcode 4.3.2. I renamed the git subdirectory to IDEGit-DISABLED.ideplugin. No missing component error messages yet. Thanks!

Comment: Xcode SVN was like a terminator that never die! And finally you succeeded! Tanks!!!

Comment: +1  Confirmed: in XCode 4.3.3 I had to rename the IDESubversion part of the file, leaving the extension instact, and XCode would then launch. Thanks, great answer!

Comment: I applied this solution to Xcode 4.5 It does disable Subversion plugin. Thanks!

Comment: My trick is simply `sudo chmod 0 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDE{Subversion,Git}.ideplugin`

Comment: Thanks! Works also on Xcode 5(preview 4). The path is same as for 4.3+

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

1. Window -> Organizer
2. Repositories
3. Select your repository
4. Click the "-" button at the bottom of the Organizer window

Unfortunately, it seems that you have to do this every time you restart Xcode.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the only way, and you're right, it just re-binds when you re-launch. Accepting...

Comment: FYI, I've logged a ticket (9316273) in Apple's Radar bug tracking system, requesting the ability to disable change tracking for a given working copy.

Comment: Another FYI - Apple have accepted this is a bug, so it may be fixed in the future...

Answer (score 7):

XCode 5.1 now has this option in the settings, and it's called `"Source Control"`:

[image: Disable source control]

Answer (score 2):

In xcode 5 the [repository option has been moved](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_5_0.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012953-SW14). It is now in `XCode > Preferences > Accounts`. Select your repository and click - at the bottom to delete it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since the /Developer directory no longer exists, the IDESubversion.ideplugin has been relocated in Xcode version 4.3

The new path is: /Applications/Xcode/Contents/Plugins/IDESubversion.ideplugin

Comment: Removing both IDESubversion.ideplugin and IDEGit.ideplugin caused an error when launching Xcode: "Missing required components. Reinstall the Xcode Tools."  This is in Xcode 4.3.2.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not in front of my XCode IDE, but try this:

1. Double click the project to set the settings
2. Select "Subversion" in the SCM box and "Edit"
3. Select "Disable SCM"

This should, at the very least, get rid of your console statements.

Comment: Thanks Rick, but I can't find the SCM box you're referring to in my project settings... Remember this is Xcode 4 I'm dealing with here, not Xcode 3

Comment: I apologize for that Mark.  I was just going from memory.  I'll wait to get home and validate further.  Although I use SVN with my projects, there's no "SCM" option in your menu, to configure your repositories?  Perhaps you project name is inadvertently in that repository listing.  Also, you project settings, you should have a selection for "Project Roots & SCM."  You can validate here that your project is not associated with a repository.

Comment: I'm thinking that it's reading the SVN directories and assuming it needs to handle the SVN connection.