# Remove git from project in Xcode 4

Tags: xcode, git

I just created a new project in Xcode 4 and I guess I left the "Create local git repository for this project" box checked. Now, I would like to remove this version control since I want to run the project with svn only. Is this possible or do I have to create a new project from scratch?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Just remove the .git directory in the project folder. You should close the project in Xcode first to be safe.

Comment: Hey, thanx for the answer. However, when I did this I couldn't open the project again. I just got the "No Editor" message in an empty pane. I have now decided not to waste more time and created a new project and moved everything.

Comment: Huh, strange, I just tried it myself and it worked fine. Of course, the repo is still listed in the Organizer, but you can just remove it there afterwards. But the project itself opened fine for me. I wonder what happened in your case.

Comment: I did this and it worked fine. Anyway the right side, there's a section "Source Control" which indicates green dot and git information. It's still there. How can I get rid of this?

Answer (score 65):

I had the same problem. Here are the steps to resolving this.

1. Go to the Organizer (under window menu option)
2. Go to Repositories
3. Look at the bottom left corner for the minus button
4. Select the project to be removed from GIT
5. Press the minus icon
6. It should be removed

This works, even though the class files still have the symbol next to them. Clicking them then clicking another file gets rid of the icon.

Hope this works.

Comment: I had already tried this. However, when I restart Xcode the repository gets recreated. Wonder if it is the same for you...

Comment: Mine works perfectly, but I did save the files after I removed the repository.

Comment: This + Shivan's suggestion only work if you want NO git control. If you're like me, and just want clean/logical command line or GUI control (versus Xcode's svn-like approach to git integration), you'll have to use a more nuclear option (like killing the git plugin for Xcode) unfortunately.

Comment: Same for me, it gets recreated, and I already removed the .git folder.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to disable Git support in Xcode 4 you'll have to rename "/Developer/Library/Xcode/PrivatePlugIns/IDEGit.ideplugin" to something other than .ideplugin.

Comment: I tried that, but Xcode now throws an error and says it needs to be reinstalled. Is there some kind of plugin registry where I need to change something else?

Comment: Yea this doesn't work as of Xcode 4.2.1, and unfortunately they still haven't added any option to disable git within the preferences pane, so I'm once again forced to cope with apple's version control bugs.

Comment: I was able to defeat this by moving the real plugin out of the way, copying IDESubversion.ideplugin to IDEGit.ideplugin, and then editing to the Info.plist to have the identifier that the original Git plugin had.

Comment: @rich.e: +1. Apples' QA sucks. They should fire the entire bunch and start over (that's if they have a QA department)

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem.  I followed the steps from [this](http://thompsonng.blogspot.com/2012/03/xcode-remove-local-git-repository.html) blog post and all worked fine for me.  I was using Xcode 4.2 on OS X 10.7.3.

I think the trick is making sure to delete the invisible ".git" folder in the project directory via the command line,... in addition to deleting the repositories via the Xcode GUI.

I'm now using SourceTree with Mercurial on BitBucket, and am a very happy camper!  :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can easily do that using

```
rm -rf .git
rm -rf .gitignore
```

Answer (score 3):

Open Terminal and Type

**Terminal**

```
$ cd /RootOfProjectFile
$ rm -rf .git 
$ rm -rf .gitignore
```

**Manual Delete**

Open Terminal and type

```
$ defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE
$ killall Finder
```

simply open the project in finder **delete** the **.git** and **.gitignore** from **root/** (Where project file is present)