# Remove source control for Xcode project

Tags: xcode, git

I've been using source control on an Xcode project for awhile, but now I don't want to use source control.

How do you remove source control from a project in Xcode?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

There are three ways. Method 1 will disable source control for all projects. Method 2 will delete the link to a single repository for all projects. Method 3 will remove the link to a repository for a single project. I think Method 3 is the one you are looking for.

1: Through Source Control Management Preferences

In Xcode, choose **Xcode-> Preferences**, then select **Source Control** and uncheck **Enable Source Control** option.

[image]

2: Go to **Xcode->Preference->Accounts->Repositories** and delete them.

[image]

3: You can do it **manually** this way: [Show Hidden Files on your Mac](http://osxdaily.com/2009/02/25/show-hidden-files-in-os-x/) and delete all the `.svn` or `.git` or `.tf` files (according to the source control) folders from the project.

Example svn directory:

[image]

Comment: This will remove the remote repository, but not remove the project from source control.

Comment: Method 1 will disable source control for all projects. Method 2 will delete the link to a single repository for all projects. Method 3 will remove the link to a repository for a single project. I think Method 3 is the one required. Other methods may affect other projects. So be cautious.

Comment: Thanks a lot,saved my time

Comment: glad to hear that! @ioSana

Answer (score 12):

The steps for Xcode 5 are the same as [the steps for Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5526383/1445366):

> Just remove the `.git` directory in the project folder. You should close the project in Xcode first to be safe.

Comment: Thanks, this help me. The .git file is hidden by default, here is the commands to view them: defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES. Change the YES to NO to hide them again. Also, after running the command hold the ‘option/alt’ key, and right click on the Finder icon in the dock and click Relaunch.

Comment: Command-shift '.' will show hidden folders and files in finder

Comment: Aaron Brager's answer still works in Xcode 13. It's simple to use when combined with @noelicus's comment

Answer (score 4):

1. Quit XCode.
2. Open Terminal.
3. Navigate to the root directory of the project.
4. Type `find ./ -name .svn -exec rm -rf {} \;`.
5. Open your project.

Your project should be disconnected from all repositories.

**NOTE:** The command searches for all filenames with extension `.svn` and removes *(recursively and forcefully)* all of them.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I got to delete repositories in Xcode, below are the easy steps:

1. Disable Source Control in your Xcode project,     i.e: **Xcode -> Preference -> Source Control**
   [image: How to Disable Source Control in Xcode]
2. **Quit Xcode** then
3. Open **Terminal** and type: **cd (your project root path or folder), press enter**
4. Type: **rm -rf .git**
5. **Close Terminal** and
6. Finally, Open your project in Xcode and **when you re-enable your source control, you will see the old repository is deleted.**

Answer (score 2):

To remove the current remote just execute this command

```
rm -rf .git
```