# How to delete files or folders in a git repository using Xcode?

Tags: xcode, git

My project had several folders that accidentally got added to my GitHub repository. I could delete them (one file at a time) from the GitHub website but that is tedious for a large number of files. I tried using `git` on the command line but it was conflicting with the Xcode source control updates. I would just like to do it graphically in Xcode if possible.

The closest Xcode question that I could find was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21198514/xcode-5-remove-source-control-for-project), but it was about removing source control altogether, which I don't want to do.

I struggled with this for quite some time but it turned out to be fairly easy. I am sharing my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as you [have your project already connected to a remote GitHub repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32498035/3681880), all you have to do is use Finder to delete the files or folders.

Then go to **Source Control** and choose **Commit** and after that **Push**.

[image]

This will delete the files from your GitHub repository without you having to use the command line.