# Xcode 7 Git Setup Fail: unable to auto-detect email address

Tags: ios, xcode, git, version-control, git-config

When enabling Git Repository Source Control for a new project on Xcode 7, it shows:

[image]

However, even after I setup user.name and user.email in terminal:

```
git config --global  user.name "John"
git config --global  user.email "john@example.com"
```

I checked and see from Terminal using

```
 git config --global -l
```

The result shows: [image]

I also checked local config in the project folder using:

```
 git config --local -l
```

user.name and user.email were not set locally.

But I still cannot commit and the same message from Xcode pop up.
Any ideas what's going wrong? Please help!

Comment: In the config file of the GIT. Change the user.name and user.email values with your name and email in both local and global.  Then try to commit and push.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution:

1. Go to project folder, look for ./git directory
2. Open the file "config" with TextEditor.
3. Terminal git config command seems not applied to this config file correctly.It was like this:
   [image]
4. I changed it to
   [image]
   and saved.
5. Commit and everything works!

Side Note: about how to find the hidden .git in project directory. 
[Xcode 5 - remove source control for project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21198514/xcode-5-remove-source-control-for-project)
[Show hidden file in Mac](http://osxdaily.com/2009/02/25/show-hidden-files-in-os-x/)

Answer (score 0):

In the terminal

```
$ git config --global user.name "Your Name"
$ git config --global user.name
Your Name

$ git config --global user.email "Your email ID"
$ git config --global user.email
Your email ID
```

In the local(for a particular repository)
In the terminal goto the working directory

```
$ git config user.name "Your Name"
$ git config user.name
Your Name

$ git config user.email "Your Email ID"
$ git config user.email
Your Email ID
```