# how to remove source control in the project (Xcode )

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, github

There is no way to delete the source control in Xcode.
The delete button is disabled.
[my screen view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZnUX.png)
Does anyone know how to delete all the source control in the Xcode

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21198514/xcode-5-remove-source-control-for-project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This delete button for deleting branch. If you want to delete Source control. Please delete .git folder from your project folder.
Please check screenshot. if you are not able to see '.git' folder. Enable 'See hidden files' in your mac.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

While in the root of the project directory, run `rm -r .git/` to delete the entire Git version control repository. Be warned, you will lose all Git history (commits, branches, etc)