# How to disable Xcode 5 Source Control from terminal / command line?

Tags: xcode, command-line, crash, terminal, xcode5

I am using Xcode 5.0.2 and yesterday I did nothing special but used its source control function to check out and update from svn.

Today, Xcode continues crashing over and over again when it launches. I googled a solution that is disabling the source control in Xcode's Preference.

But since it crashes when it launches, I don't have change to go into the Preference Panel to do the operations.

**So is there command that I can do in Terminal to disable the source control of Xcode?**

**!!!UPDATE:**

actually this is not the real problem I ran into. I thought my Xcode crash because of the source control issue. So I send this post and got an answer quickly. Thanks @zzyclark .

But after I did as the post in the link said, my Xcode still crash. I've used other way and got the problem done.

**I am gonna keep this post for the people who really want to disable Xcode source control in Terminal.
But if the admin think this is not the propriety. You could delete this post.**

Comment: and why the heck did you not say WHAT you did to get the problem fixed, even if it was not related to source control?

Comment: @iCode4Food I modified a os file that contains the system version. I modified the mavricks system version and xcode version to submit to the app store. So I probably restore the file and reinstall the xcode because I really forget the details. And it worked. If you've run into this issue, you could try it.

Answer (score 0):

rather than close it in terminal, can u check this. This is used to disable the version control of xcode 4 by modifying the file name extension.[Can you disable version control integration in Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466254/can-you-disable-version-control-integration-in-xcode-4)