# Xcode giving me 'Obstructing' warning because I am no longer using SVN, switched to Perforce

Tags: xcode, svn, version-control, perforce

my first post so hopefully I am clear enough with my problem.

I started a new project about a year ago in Xcode 3.x.y (iOS project), everything was going well, but I wanted to use some sort of source control.  I had heard about SVN on a website so I gave it a shot and put the repositories on a USB external hard drive.  Everything was going great, then I decided to switch to Perforce because other people on the project were used to it. After doing that I formatted the usb hard drive to use it for other purposes.

Fast forward to last week: I installed Xcode 4.x, and I am getting all kinds of warnings when I build.  The 2 I am getting are:

> game_name.app.dSYM
>   Obstructing
>   file://localhost/projects/game_name/build/Release-iphonesimulator/game_name.app.dSYM/:
>   warning: Obstructing: /projects/game_name/build/Release-iphonesimulator/game_name.app.dSYM is blocking item under version control

and

> fx_swish_01.wav
>   Missing File
>   /projects/game_name/fx_swish_01.wav
>   file://localhost/projects/game_name/fx_swish_01.wav: warning: Missing file: /projects/game_name/fx_swish_01.wav is missing from working copy

Those are the 2 errors, but I have 113 total (about 10 of the obstructing, and 100 of the missing).  I'm assuming this is because the project somehow still thinks I am using SVN for my SCM, when in fact I am using ONLY perforce from outside of Xcode.

Does anyone have a clue on what I need to do?  I don't care if files get clobbered, ignored, deleted, whatever... I have everything in perforce that I think I need.  Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I got some of the 'missing from working copy' warnings by doing: svn delete  --force.  Is this going to bite me later down the line?  I couldn't commit, but it did remove the warning.  Here is a copy of what I did:

```
$ svn delete fx_swish_01.wav 
svn: Use --force to override this restriction
svn: 'fx_swish_01.wav' has local modifications

$ svn delete fx_swish_01.wav --force
D fx_swish_01.wav

$ svn commit -m "deleted fx_swish_01.wav"
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Directory '/projects/game_name/build/Release-iphonesimulator/game_name.app.dSYM/.svn' containing working copy admin area is missing

$ svn delete fx_swish_02.wav 
D fx_swish_02.wav

$ svn delete fx_swish_03.wav 
D fx_swish_03.wav

$ svn delete fx_swish_04.wav 
D fx_swish_04.wav

$ svn delete hey_what_a_crowd.mp3
D hey_what_a_crowd.mp3

$ cd build/Release-iphonesimulator/

$ ls
game_name.app       game_name.app.dSYM  game_name.app_old.dSYM

$ svn delete game_name.app.dSYM
svn: Directory 'game_name.app.dSYM/.svn' containing working copy admin area is missing

$ svn delete game_name.app.dSYM --force
D game_name.app.dSYM
svn: Directory 'game_name.app.dSYM/.svn' containing working copy admin area is missing
```

As you can see, I got the .wav files to remove and it seems to not give me those warnings anymore.  The game_name.app.dSYM thin is still not working though... the admin area is missing?  I'm sure if that file existed at one point, it sure don't anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Since you switched away from svn, you can delete all the .svn folders that are probably left over from your previous version control efforts.

Checking out a fresh copy from Perforce should also work, provided you have not checked-in the .svn folders into p4, in which case you should delete them all from p4.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will give it a shot tomorrow!  I was assuming there was data in the project files themselves that were to blame, I hope it's this easy!

Comment: Hmm.. I don't see any .svn folders anywhere in my root folder and anywhere deeper.

Comment: The .svn folders are hidden. One way to show them is to use the terminal command. defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles YES. This will show all hidden files on Mac. Or, you can manually run `svn status` command in the folder to see if it's under subversion. If it's not under subversion you'll get a message "svn warning:  '.' is not a working copy". If you don't want to track changes to these files, you can use `find . -type d -name .svn -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf` to get rid of the svn status. Use this command if you're sure. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

The answers provided in this post should help you solve the warnings you are seeing that pertain to missing files:  [Missing file warnings showing up after upgrade to XCode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292291/missing-file-warnings-showing-up-after-upgrade-to-xcode-4)