# how to remove all the normal png in the xcode project

Tags: xcode, bash, png

I want to remove all the images which has the name without the "@2x", and I want to write a shell script to finish this. This is what I do:

```
#!/bin/bash

dir="/Users/me/Workspace/"
cd $dir
all_pngs=`find . -name "*.png" | sort -u`
for png in $all_pngs
do
    #    echo "$png"
    #get the dirname
    dirname=`dirname $png`
    #get the filename without dir
    filename=`basename $png`
    #get name without suffix
    name=`echo "$filename" | cut -d '.' -f1`
    realname=`echo "$name" | grep -v "@2x"`
    if [ -n $realname ]; then
        echo "$realname"
    fi

done
```

My problem is that I don't know how can I find the name without the "@2x".

Comment: This isn't the primary issue with the script, but see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7039579/3076724) if you want to loop over `find` output safely (i.e. won't mangle filenames with spaces, newlines, etc...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you're trying to do with the rest of your script, but just something like this should work

```
find /Users/me/Workspace/ -type f -name '*.png' \! -name '*@2x*' -exec echo rm '{}' +
```

Remove the `echo` when you're confident that's what you want.

Since the `! exp` has a higher precedence in find than the implied `-a` between tests and actions the above gets treated as

```
find /Users/me/Workspace/ (-type f) AND (-name '*.png') AND (! -name '*@2x*') AND (-exec echo rm '{}' +)
```

Comment: there is another problem, the references to the removed files become error(it becomes red), then how to delete the error references in Xcode?

Comment: @YueLiu Not sure, haven't used `xcode` in a while. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5545171/3076724) is somewhat on point, though might be worth asking again if you don't find a better solution.

Comment: I had found a solution with this problem. I just delete the folder which the deleted files belongs to, and then added it again.

Answer (score 0):

You have used many unwanted operation in your for loop which are not necessary( but exactly any purpose of it?). You need simple logic in your `for..loop` as below. OR in one sentence you can use nice answer given by @BroSlow

You can check if your file name contain "@2x" or not like

```
if [[ $png = *@2x* ]] //Yes it contain "@2x"
then
    echo "File name contain @2x keep as it is."
else
    //remove file // rm -f $png
fi
```

Using `grep`

```
if grep -o "@2x" <<<"$png" >/dev/null
then
    echo "File name contain @2x keep as it is."
else
    //remove file // rm -f $png
fi
```