# Xcode weird random error that doesn't go away

Tags: ios, xcode, caching, plist

I have a regular project i'm working on for a while - 
I've edited the plist file, which caused some problem, so i've reverted to the old plist file (where all used to work), but the following errors always show and dont go away,

[image]

I've tried cleaning the project (Cmd+Shift+k , Cmd+Opt+Shift+k) , Tried resetting my pbjprox, tried clearing ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ and /var/folders

Nothing works, and i guess the errors are cached somewhere that i can't think of...

Would appreciate your hints about this

Shai

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easy to fix - your files are not on location where Xcode expects them. Just delete the file from your project and add it again.

If this doesn't work, it can be a collision with your versioning system - see [Missing file warnings showing up after upgrade to XCode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292291/missing-file-warnings-showing-up-after-upgrade-to-xcode-4/5379013#5379013)

Answer (score 0):

I would copy these files into another location (outside the project folder) and then remove them from the project and add them back (Add Files to ...).  Make sure to select Copy Items into destinations group's folder

Sounds like Xcode is a little confused about the association of these files to your project.